# How to format currencies on MAKE.com using a number as input

Tags: make.com, format-currency

I have an automation where I am getting numbers as an input and it is plain number without any formating

Example
`3500`
`15000`
`55000`
`300`

Here is a screenshot on how it looks on MAKE
[Make screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EwRf.png)

These numbers are actually currencies (US) and I want to format them with commas and all.
.ie. like this
`3,500`
`15,000`

Could anyone help me figure out how to do it

I used format number function but couldn't figure out how to do em.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following formula and replace number with your input.

```
{{get(split(formatNumber(1000000; 3; "."; ","); "."); 1)}}
```